# Three.js move in the lookat direction

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js, controls

I have been trying to use pointerlock controls to move in the way the camera is looking. Recently the getDirection() method was added and I use it like this.

```
if ( moveForward ){
    velocity.x += 20.0 * controls.getDirection().x * delta;
    controls.getObject().translateX( velocity.x * delta );
}
```

It sort of works until (I'm guessing here) the errors add up and it starts moving whereever it wants when I hit the forward key. The idea is that I look with the mouse and then I want to move in that direction, Zero gravity, I am not constrained in any direction. Can someone help? I am working with r72.

Edit:

I found taht FlyControls are closer to what I want, but if you check the example: [Fly controls](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_fly)

It pans in direction wherever the mouse was last. I want the camera to move with the mouse, at the same speed, and if the mouse doesn't move, camera shouldn't move either. Any ideas?

Comment: check this example http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html i think this is what you want or you can modify it to match your idea

Comment: I've seen the example a thousand times. I even know it by heart, hehe, but it only moves on 2D, I don't know how to combine it so that it moves on 3D. I mean, it jumps, but I'd like it so that when I press moveForward it will go on the looking direction.

Comment: you can combine the movement from [fly controls](http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_fly) with the mouse look of pointerlock (or modify it to not lock the mouse)